# Tensorflow Object Detection API eval.py - 'metrics' referenced before assignment

Tags: tensorflow, eval, object-detection, object-detection-api

Tensorflow Object Detection API training works flawless, but when I tried to evaluate the work by eval.py with the following command,

`python3 eval.py --logtosderr --checkpoint_dir=training/ --eval_dir=eval/ --pipeline_config_path=training/faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_oid.config`

I got the following error,

```
paperspace@psnu680y1:~/models-master/research/object_detection$ python3 eval.py --logtostderr --checkpoint_dir = training/ --eval_dir=eval/ --pipeline_config_path=training/faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_oid.config
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "eval.py", line 133, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/home/paperspace/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "eval.py", line 129, in main
    FLAGS.checkpoint_dir, FLAGS.eval_dir)
  File "/home/paperspace/models-master/research/object_detection/evaluator.py" line 210, in evaluate
    save_graph_dir=(eval_dir if eval_config.save_graph else ''))
  File "/home/paperspace/models-master/research/object_detection/eval_util.py", line 393, in repeated_checkpoint_run
    return metrics
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'metrics' referenced before assignment'
```

I have checked the code, 'metrics' variable should come from evaluator.py evaluate function, but because of a reason, it does not.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should also post the evaluation section of your config file

Comment: I have added to my eval_util.py  `from tensorflow.python.platform import tf_logging as logging`, to be able to see all logging information. After import the logging, and run the code, I saw the message " No module found in =." . Then, I checked the eval_util.py, and saw that there were a problem with checkpoint path. I don't know what was the problem, but I rewrite the flags and bom! It worked pretty well.

Comment: I had the same issue. The **--checkpoint_dir** argument must be the folder containing the files: model.ckpt-xxxx.data, model.ckpt-xxxx.index and model.ckpt-xxxx.meta

Answer (score 2):

checkpoint_dir should be the output directory of export_inference_graph.py
It contains the model.ckpt